# Can Pex process the interface with the parameter of a class type

Tags: automated-tests, pex

i have installed Academic version of pex and roles .

I wrote the following code in Visual Studio 2010.but pex just gave a null pointer as the input. doesn't the pex support the class type? please help me.

the test inferface is Test.

source code:

```
public class ClassForPex
{

public int a;
public int b;
ClassForPex(int x, int y)
{
    a = x;
    b = y;
}
};

public static class StringExtensions
{

public static int Test(ClassForPex cjh)
{
    if (cjh.a > cjh.b)
        return cjh.a;
    else
    {
        return cjh.b;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a factory for supplying your ClassForPex instances to the tests. Look at this article to see how to do that.

Using of Factory in Pex - http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2009/04/13/using-of-factory-in-pex.aspx